# JHipster Gateway as Application Platform?

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry, jhipster-gateway

Is the JHipster Gateway meant to be just a load balancer/proxy or is it meant to be a platform to add UI functionality to in a Gateways for Applications pattern?

Help me understand why the Gateway is generated and why its not an application like the registry (which is ready to run).

Likewise, why is the UAA server-generated and also not an application-ready-to-run like the registry? What are we intended to customize and extend here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gateway application is entry point for your application, it's typically your frontend application (UI), it is where you have to integrate all your backend RestAPIs (or microservices).  Gateway application also can be used to expose your customer-facing APIs.

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).